# Get Data back to calling Fragment from 2nd Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Scenario**
I got multiple fragments that are going to call DialogFragment#1 which further got 3 Buttons and each button opens another DialogFragment#2.

What I want here is to get a String value that user selected via DialogFragment#2 and send it back to callingFragment(can be any one out of 6) to set textView Text.

I can do this by keeping different DialogFragment classes for each 6 fragments but I want to keep 1 class for DialogFragment #1 and 1 for DialogFragment  #2 and use is for each fragment because the functionality is same for all...

Possible Solutions I tried but no success
1 - Tried to get callingFragment Name but when I try to call public Method of fragment its not working
callingFragment.setText(text)
callingFragment should be 1 of any 6 fragments...

2 - OnActivityResult as well but no success...

Comment: Use persistence - SharedPreferences will likely do the job

Comment: Android does not recommend showing 2 dialog fragment (which are not full screen)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this can be implemented as the following:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

private lateinit var currentFragment: CurrentFragment?

    private val host by lazy {
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_nav_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    }

    override fun showQuantityDialog() {
        currentFragment= host.childFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment as CurrentFragment
        navController.navigate(ViewProductFragmentDirections.actionViewProductFragmentToQuantityDialogFragment())
    }

    // This is a callback from your dialog
    override fun setQuantity(quantity: Int) {
        viewProductFragment?. ... set what ever you want
        viewProductFragment = null 
    }
}
```

So you save a reference to the current fragment **before** you open the dialog.